# Selection sort in linked list java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, selection-sort

My program is not sorting the list and I can't figure out the problem. 
The list is the same before sorting and after sorting.

```
 public void SelectionSort(){
    for (Node index = head; ((index != null)&&(index.getnext()!=null)); index = index.getnext()) {
          Node min = index;
          for (Node test = min.getnext(); test != null; test = test.getnext()) {
            if (test.getAcc().compareTo(min.getAcc()) < 0){
                min = test; 
            } 
          }
          if(index!=min){
              Node temp = new Node();
              temp=index;
              index=min;
              min =temp;
          }  
    }
}
```

Below is my class Node:

```
public class Node {
    private int ID;
    private String Acc;
    private String Symbol;
    private String Function;
    private String UniGene;
    private String Chromosome;
    private Node next;

    public Node(){

    }
    public Node(int id, String acc,String unigene, String symbol, String chromosome, String function){
        ID=id;
        Acc=acc;
        Symbol=symbol;
        UniGene = unigene;
        Chromosome = chromosome;
        Function=function;
    }
    public void displayNode() // display 
    {
        System.out.print("{"+ID+","+Acc+","+Symbol+","+Function+"} \n");
    }
    int getID(){
        return ID;
    }
    String getAcc(){
        return Acc;
    }
    String getUniGene(){
        return UniGene;
    }
    String getSymbol(){
        return Symbol;
    }
    String getChromosome(){
        return Chromosome;
    }
    String getFunction(){
        return Function;
    }
    void setnext(Node newnode)
    {
        next = newnode;
    }
    Node getnext()
    {
        return next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to step through your code using a debugger?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and read [ask].  It is considered off-topic to post your code and ask others to debug it for you.  You are expected to make some effort, such as tracing the code in a debugger to identify the step you don't understand, THEN ask a specific question. 99% of the time you will find the problem on your own.

Comment: i tried the debugger, still cant figure out!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you need to take care of the `next` pointer when you move nodes. In your original code you just swap 2 references, but you don't change the order in the list:

```
          Node next = min.getnext();
          min.setnext(index);
          index.setnext(next);
```

This won't work directly, but the problem lies there. You'll need to save the "previous" node, and set previous.setnext(index) or something like that.

BTW:

```
 Node temp = new Node();
 temp=index;
```

You create a new Node, but you don't use it, 'cause in the next line you assign index to temp.

```
Node temp = index;
```

Comment: thank you. what i did was just changing the values instead of the whole node... so the next pointer stays the same only the values are changed. And it is working :)